# Access an indexed type by index on a BehaviorSubject from a component in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular component I have an indexed collection that I want to be able to access buy index in my markup but I also want to be able to update it asynchronously. To that end I'm using a BehaviorSubject, like this:

```
interface IDictionary<T> {
    [key: string] : T;
}

interface Biscuit {
     name: string;

     price: number;
}

export class MyComponent {
      public myContent: Dictionary<IBiscuit> = {};
 
      public myContentBehavior = new BehaviorSubject<Dictionary<IBiscuit>>({});

      public myListBehavior = new BehaviorSubject<Array<IBiscuit>>([]);

      public biscuitNames = [];

      constructor() {
          const bourbon = {name: "bourbon", cost: 0.5});
          const hobnob = {name: "hobnob", cost: 0.8});
          // and so on.

          this.myContent["bourbon"] = bourbon;
          this.myContent["hobnob"] = hobnob;

          this.myContentBehavior.next(this.myContent);
          this.myListBehavior.next([bourbon, hobnob]);
          this.biscuitNames = [ "bourbon", "hobnob" ];
      }
      
}
```

All of this works, but when I want to call them from mark-up, although I can treat `myListBehavior` as a list, I can't treat `myContentBehavior` as a dictionary.

```
<h1>Biscuits!</h1>

<div *ngFor="let name of biscuitNames">
    <p>Collection cost: {{ myContent[name].cost }}</p>
    <p>Behaviour cost: {{ myContentBehavior[name].cost | async}} <-- This will fail </p>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let biscuit of myListBehavior | async" >
     <p>List cost: {{biscuit.cost}}</p>
</div>
```

This will raise an error message saying `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'BehaviorSubject<Dictionary<Biscuit>>'`.

How can I use the index with the BehaviorSubject?

Answer (score 0):

Writing the question made me realise that the problem is that while it is unresolved by the async pipe, `myContentBehavior` is a `BehaviorSubject` so it doesn't have any of the properties of a collection. To use the index I have to let that resolve first:

```
<p>Behaviour cost: {{ (myContentBehavior | async)![name].cost }} </p>
```

At compile time, Angular can't tell whether this will return anything or not, so you need the `!` operator to tell Angular you are confident this will have a value and then it will be down to you to make sure it has a value from the start. We already know that it does in this case because we're handing it an empty object on creation.